# Entity framework extended throws DynamicProxy exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-extended

When trying to do bulk updates using EntityFramework.Extended I get one of two exceptions.

Looking at the [example](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Batch-Update-and-Delete) I tried:

```
context.ProcessJobs.Where(job => true).Update(job => new ProcessJob
{
    Status = ProcessJobStatus.Processing,
    StatusTime = DateTime.Now,
    LogString = "Processing"
});
```

I got the following exception:

> 'EntityFramework.Reflection.DynamicProxy' does not contain a definition for 'InternalQuery'
>
> ...
>
> System.Core.dll!System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, object arg0) + 0x153 bytes
>
> EntityFramework.Extended.dll!EntityFramework.Extensions.ObjectQueryExtensions.ToObjectQuery(System.Linq.IQueryable query) + 0x2db bytes
>
> EntityFramework.Extended.dll!EntityFramework.Extensions.BatchExtensions.Update(System.Linq.IQueryable source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> updateExpression) + 0xe9 bytes
>
> EntityFramework.Extended.dll!EntityFramework.Extensions.BatchExtensions.Update(System.Linq.IQueryable source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> updateExpression) + 0xe9 bytes

Based on a [github issue](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/issues/43), I tried :

```
var c = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<ProcessJob>();
c.Update(job => new ProcessJob
{
    Status = ProcessJobStatus.Processing,
    StatusTime = DateTime.Now,
    LogString = "Processing"
});
```

Which results in the exception (probably same error as reported [here](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/issues/68))

> 'EntityFramework.Reflection.DynamicProxy' does not contain a definition for 'EnsureMetadata'
>
> ...
>
> EntityFramework.Extended.dll!EntityFramework.Mapping.ReflectionMappingProvider.FindMappingFragment(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable itemCollection, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntitySet entitySet) + 0xc1e bytes
>
> EntityFramework.Extended.dll!EntityFramework.Mapping.ReflectionMappingProvider.CreateEntityMap(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery query) + 0x401 bytes
>
> EntityFramework.Extended.dll!EntityFramework.Mapping.ReflectionMappingProvider.GetEntityMap(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery query) + 0x58 bytes
>
> EntityFramework.Extended.dll!EntityFramework.Mapping.MappingResolver.GetEntityMap(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery query) + 0x9f bytes
>
> EntityFramework.Extended.dll!EntityFramework.Extensions.BatchExtensions.Update(System.Linq.IQueryable source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> updateExpression) + 0x1c8 bytes

I tried the latest version for EF5, and I upgraded to EF6 to see if the latest version works, but I get the same problem. We use Code First.

I am not sure how to proceed, I've started trying to understand how the EntityFramework.Extensions code works. But I am wondering whether I will have to fall back to using a stored procedure or SQL, which neither are ideal for our setup.

Does anyone know what these problems are, or have any ideas about how to work out what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that you can ignore this error. I had CLR runtime exceptions debug option turned on. I followed through the source code, and then downloaded it and started debugging.

It seems that the exception being thrown initially is expected and it retries with some other options. Unfortunately I didn't have time to look into the exact problem because I ran into another - but that's the subject of a different question.